# SonarQube.Integration.targets process conflicts when building a project

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, tfsbuild, microsoft-fakes

I am having an issue with building a project, with SonarQube integrated, on TFS 2015.

When I build this project without SonarQube, it builds fine. However, when SonarQube runs alongside this build, one of the project files fails to compile (specifically, it's a unit test project). I get the following error:

```
D:\Builds\....\Project\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets (235, 0)
Could not write lines to file "D:\Builds\.....\.sonarqube\out\\f_AnyCPU_Release_0213\FilesToAnalyze.txt".

The process cannot access the file 'D:\Builds\.....\Project\.sonarqube\out\f_AnyCPU_Release_0213\FilesToAnalyze.txt'` 
because it is being used by another process. 
[D:\Builds\.....\Project\\src\Apps\Solution\obj\Debug\Fakes\spi\f.csproj]
```

If anyone can offer some hints as to why this is happening, it'd be much appreciated. I've tried recreating this error with a few projects that I've written but it doesn't seem to happen. It might be specific to the project.

Comment: Would be very valuable if you could provide a reproducer. Would you mind sending the project structure to us (you can remove most of the source code I guess)?

Comment: Thanks for the response Julien. We've fixed this issue by simply upgrading our build agents and using SonarQube through the latest TFS build system (the issue came up with the XAML based builds). Please let me know if you'd like me to send you the info.

Comment: No that's fine thanks, we don't plan to put high effort on XAML based builds BTW.