# SonarQube 5.6 - MSBuild Fakes Generation failing (SonarQube.Integration.targets)

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105789/sonarqube-integration-targets-process-conflicts-when-building-a-project).

Unfortunately, this issue is coming up again after having upgraded our build machines to run on Visual Studio Online 2015's Build and Release Manager.

This is the error that I get from a solution that generates Fakes assemblies used in unit testing:

```
D:\builds\TFS2015agent_2_work\1\.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(240,5): 
error MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "D:\builds\TFS2015agent_2_work\1\.sonarqube\out\\f_AnyCPU_Release_9840\FilesToAnalyze.txt". 
The process cannot access the file 'D:\builds\TFS2015agent_2_work\1\.sonarqube\out\f_AnyCPU_Release_9840\FilesToAnalyze.txt' because it is being used by another process. [D:\builds\TFS2015agent_2_work\1\s\FakesFilePath\f.csproj] [D:\builds\TFS2015agent_2_work\1\s\FakesFileProj]
2016-09-13T20:01:37.6477261Z   GENERATEFAKES : error : project compilation failed with exit code 1 [D:\builds\TFS2015agent_2_work\1\s\FakesFilePath\]
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening? What process is causing the error? Could it possibly be related to the fakes compiling while SonarQube tries to access it?

Comment: I refered to this article to create fack unit test project (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx), then queue build with SonarQube tasks (Build definition: 1. Fetch the Quality profile from SonarQube, 2. Build solution, 3. Finish the analysis and upload the results to SonarQube, 4…), it works fine. (I am using SonarQube 6.0). What’s the different with your scenario except SonarQube version? If the project is different, you can share a simple project on the OneDrive.

Comment: Today, I tried it with SonarQube 5.6.1, it works fine too. So you can share a simple project that can reproduce that issue on the OneDrive. I will check it.

Comment: Try to check which process is using that file through Resource Monitor (search directory/file). (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565218/how-to-know-what-process-is-using-a-given-file)

Comment: Similar with this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2275#ref-commit-2f1b593, can you try duncanpMS's workaround (use the FolderDisambiguator ) to see if it can works?