# SonarQube fails on MS fake projects

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

I have the same issue as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105789/sonarqube-integration-targets-process-conflicts-when-building-a-project) on TFS2015. C# test project on VS2013. SonarQube 5.6, Scaner 2.1:

> [error]D:\TFS\agent2_work\4.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(229,5):
>
> Error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory
>   "D:\TFS\agent2_work\4.sonarqube\out\f_AnyCPU_Release_8471". The
>   process cannot access the file 'FilesToAnalyze.txt' because it is
>   being used by another process.
>   [D:\TFS\agent2_work\4\s\Testing\MSTestUnitTests\obj\x64\Release\Fakes\smbm\f.csproj] 2016-07-14T18:06:53.4356397Z
>   54>D:\TFS\agent2_work\4.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets(229,5):
>   error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory
>   "D:\TFS\agent2_work\4.sonarqube\out\f_AnyCPU_Release_8471". The
>   process cannot access the file 'FilesToAnalyze.txt' because it is
>   being used by another process.
>   [D:\TFS\agent2_work\4\s\Testing\MSTestUnitTests\obj\x64\Release\Fakes\smbm\f.csproj] [D:\TFS\agent2_work\4\s\Testing.MSTestUnitTests\MSTestUnitTests.csproj]
>   [error]GENERATEFAKES(0,0): Error : project compilation failed with
>   exit code 1

Comment: Don't repost unanswered questions. Upvote it, bounty it, edit it or do whatever it takes to draw attention to it.

Comment: Seems you are also using old XAML build, did you try to  fix this issue by simply upgrading build agents and using SonarQube through the vNext build system  just as D.R. commented ?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT, no we are using TFS 2015 vNext, looking to upgrate to VSTS and for Linux we are on thr open-source agent vsts-agent with .NET core and stuff. But... how it is relevant to ** failure of fakes generation ** ?